# Proving consistency for an estimator.

Tags: statistics

Let $Y_1,Y_2,...,Y_n$ be a random sample of size $n$ from a normal pdf having $\mu=0$. Show that $S_{n}^{2} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n {Y_{i}^{2}}$ is a consistent estimator for $\sigma^2= Var(Y)$.

Comment: I guess the easiest way is to create an example and show that the estimator your example is not consistent.

Answer (score 2):

**Hints:**

1. write the definition of the consistent estimator
2. compute the mean and the variance of $S^2_n$
3. apply [Chebyshev's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality#Probabilistic_statement) to $X = S_n^2$

Comment: Thank you! This was very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Apply the law of large numbers of the sequence $Y_1^2,Y_2^2,\ldots,Y_n^2$.